# How is the best way to import data into SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql-server

I want to import data into SQL Server Express, from Access, Excel and txt files. I'm creating a decent database, and I must to import these old formated data. When working with few records, I copy and paste directly through Visual Web Developer DB Explorer.

But now I'm dealing with a few more records (40k). I think copy/paste unsafe, slow and unprofessional. I haven't any other interfaces to control SQL server. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an "Import and Export Wizard" that comes with SQL Express. It allows you to import from Access, Excel, ODBC, SQL Client etc.

Comment: +1, here is the link of how to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a clear answer but I really think MSACCESS 2000 or higher is a very versatile tool for doing this..

Linking in tables and using Append queries to other linked tables works really well, plus utilizing the power of VBA helps in some cases too (like calling a vba function from query designer (like InStr or Mid etc..) (if your familiar with this)

Does anyone else agree?

Comment: I think something like that might be the best way. I believe a SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) script is what to use for the enterprise-level SQL server, but for Express you are limited in your options.

Answer (score 2):

The BCP (Bulk Copy) works well for importing into SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

There is also the "bulk insert" command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx which has the caveat that the file must be physically accessible from the server.

Both of these methods can import comma delimited files, so you'd need to be able to create those from your data source.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend loading all the objects from one SQL table into a JSON object and then indexing through an array of object and translating them into the new table.  I have some open source MySQL to JavaScript bridge code that can help with this if you need.

Answer (score -1):

In case you have not found a solution to this yet, try http://www.razorsql.com/download_win.html

I am not affiliated with them, but I was looking for this same solution and this is working.

Comment: Welcome. This question already has an accepted answer. So it would be nice if you explained in details how the link you provided would help to solve the problem in a different way.